# Colour coding cells based on other cells with condition formatting already applied in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to have the cells on the right linked to the cells on the left, so if the top cell under harsh acceleration is red I need the top cell under the count of harsh acceleration to be red.
The cells on the left are calculated based on miles driven.

[image: Image of data]

[Formatting of score cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8oX9.png)

[Formatting of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZBmU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Read this on how to set up your own conditional formatting.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: Thanks, but I understand how to use conditional formatting, the coloured cells are already formatted. I wanted to link the raw data on the right to the formatted cells on the left which are calculations based on distance. So if after calculation the cell is amber I want the raw data to show as amber as well. I've not seen anything that allows me to do this whilst researching.

Comment: @ClunkyCookie I assume that the first conditional formatting is not done using your own rule, but rather a pre-made formatting rule. Simply create the same rule with your own formula in the new cells, using the same inputcells as the first one. (Yes, you have to do 1 new rule for each color.

Comment: So the first image is the rules I used to format the cells on the left and I've used this same formula to apply the colours to the cells on the right in image 2. Any ideas why it failed. I was hoping there was a way of saying if cell F14 is red then make cell M14 red. Images above in question

Comment: Since you only have three colors, create three separate rules. 
Rule 1. if A2=100 then green "=A2=100"
Rule 2, if A2 >60 then yellow
Rule 3, if A2>0 then red
And make sure they are in the correct order.